# Обновление состояния кнопки при использовании паттерна MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Изучаю паттерн MVVM и наткнулся на небольшую проблему: когда делаю привязку команды к кнопке, задаю также Predicate, который отвечает за включение/отключение этой кнопки.

Так вот, когда у меня меняются параметры, отвечающие за вкл/выкл кнопки, то состояние кнопки не обновляется пока она не получит фокус (клик по ней или переключение Tab'ом). Искал решения в Интернете. В основном все ссылаются на метод `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`

Но я так и не понял, к сожалению, как его использовать. Как все-таки сделать автообновление состояния кнопки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все оказалось гораздо проще. Одно из свойств было привязано к свойству Text TextBox'а. У этого свойства нужно было указать UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged:

```
<TextBox
  AcceptsReturn="True"
  TextWrapping="Wrap"
  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
  Height="150"
  Text="{Binding Path=PRNumbers, Mode=OneWayToSource, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Удачи в написании кода!

Answer (score 1):

Если состояние вашего `Predicate` может изменяться снаружи, то у команды должно срабатывать событие `CanExecuteChanged`, чтобы оповестить интерфейс об изменении доступности.

Я, например, в командах делаю такую привязку, когда надо:

```
  Library.StateChanged += (o, a) => this.OnCanExecuteChanged();
  Library.AvaibleChanged += (o, a) => this.OnCanExecuteChanged();
```

Comment: Немного не понял где вызывать представленный вами код. Поянсите, пожалуйста. Вот часть класса RelayCommand, который используется у меня: public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {    
         add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
   remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }    
  }

Comment: @badc0de32: В команде, разумеется.

Comment: @badc0de32 там же, где вы создаете экземпляр команды. Я использую команды конкретных типов, вы по моему используете один тип с передачей ему делегатов. В обоих случаях, должна быть возможность доопределить логику.

Comment: @Monk, не пойму что такое Library в вашем коде. У меня во ViewModel команда объявляется и создается так: `public ICommand processCommand { get; private set; } processCommand = new RelayCommand(processZDC, canStartProcessZDC);` Как я сказал, я начинающий в MVVM и в WPF, поэтому не судите строго за мои, наверно, глупые вопросы :)

Comment: @badc0de32 это событие, при котором могла измениться доступность команды. Т.е. когда происходит какое то событие, нужно пересчитать доступность таких команд. Если у вас вот этот `RelayCommand` - https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.mvvm.relaycommand(v=vs.110).aspx, то вам нужно вызывать метод `RaiseCanExecuteChanged`, когда меняется доступность команды. Если событий нет - видимо вручную. Хотя тогда проще вызвать `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()`, когда опять таки меняется состояние доступности команды.

Comment: @Monk. Все равно не соображу, как и где вызывать RaiseCanExecuteChanged. Мой метод, проверяющий доступность кнопки: `private bool CanProcessZDC(object parameter)
  {
   if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PRNumbers) || !canActivateBtn)
    return false;
   return true;
  } ` Где **PRNumbers** - это публичное свойство, которое связано с текстовым полем, а **canActivateBtn** становится _true_ после удачного открытия файа.

Comment: Так очевидно же, при изменении `PRNumbers` и `canActivateBtn`.

Comment: @Monk, то есть в сеттере свойства **PRNumbers** мне нужно вызывать, например, CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested()? Это свойство у меня, кстати, автоматическое.

Comment: @badc0de32 да, это тоже решит вашу проблему. Хотя в данном случае, лучше вызывать `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` конкретной команды, если она одна такая. Т.к. иначе у вас у всех команд вызовется пересчет доступности, а это может быть дороже в плане скорости.

Comment: К сожалению, никакого эффекта. Добавил в сеттеры обоих свойств (PRumbers и canActivateBtn) вызовы RaiseCanExecuteChanged и CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() и ничего не произошло. Все по-прежнему. Использую RelayCommand как в здесь [http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/645F4DB6/84779140](http://www.getcodesamples.com/src/645F4DB6/84779140).